# magento custom module block not calling

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I Created module i try to call my category page but it not showing

**`layout.xml`**

```
<reference name="content">   
      <block type="gallery/index" name="gallery_index" template="gallery/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>
```

in static block i call this way

```
{{block type="gallery/index" name="gallery" template="gallery/index.phtml"}}
```

then i call this static block my category but it not working

**`config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MPS_Gallery>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MPS_Gallery>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <gallery>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>MPS_Gallery</module>
            <frontName>gallery</frontName>
          </args>
      </gallery>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <gallery>
              <file>gallery.xml</file>
            </gallery>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <admin>
        <routers>
            <gallery>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MPS_Gallery</module>
                    <frontName>gallery</frontName>
                </args>
            </gallery>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <gallery module="gallery">
                <title>Gallery</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>                
                <children>
                    <items module="gallery">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>gallery/adminhtml_gallery</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </gallery>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <gallery>
                            <title>gallery Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </gallery>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>    
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <gallery>
                    <file>gallery.xml</file>
                </gallery>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
  <global>
    <models>
            <gallery>
                <class>MPS_Gallery_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>gallery_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </gallery>
            <gallery_mysql4>
                <class>MPS_Gallery_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <gallery>
                        <table>gallery</table>
                    </gallery>
                </entities>
            </gallery_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <gallery_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MPS_Gallery</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </gallery_setup>
            <gallery_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </gallery_write>
            <gallery_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </gallery_read>
        </resources>
    <helpers>
      <gallery>
        <class>MPS_Gallery_Helper</class>
      </gallery>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <gallery>
        <class>MPS_Gallery_Block</class>
      </gallery>
    </blocks>
    <resources>
      <gallery_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>MPS_Gallery</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </gallery_setup>
      <gallery_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </gallery_write>
      <gallery_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </gallery_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Please add your config file code to question

Comment: Plese check my updated question

Comment: Make sure you have the file with name **gallery.xml** in `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout` and your template file **index.phtml** in `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/gallery` folder

Comment: in my frontend url it's working fine i can't able to use this my category page

Comment: is `MPS/Gallery/Block/Index.php` file is there ??

Comment: I think @Gopal's answer should work for you.

Comment: <?php   
class MPS_Gallery_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

 public function _getGalleryCollection(){
   $_galleryCollection = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter( 'status', array( "like"=>'1' ) );
            return $_galleryCollection;
        }



}

Comment: Can you add your layout file code? Under which tag you have added your block code? `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give permission to that block

> system -> permission -> Blocks -> Click **add new Block**

[image]

then **Save Block**

and Make sure your **block name should be unique**.

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.1 i did't see any Block tab

Comment: Sorry but Currently I am not having 1.9.1.1 setup to get verify @Develop